# Cart page not Working in magento2

Tags: magento2, cart

When i add product to the cart and click checkout page i am getting below error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on null in
>   /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php
>   on line 43

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try to add Other Product. I think product which u have added didn't have Price. Try to set Price from Admin for that Product

Comment: add getPrice($product) function which you have in file.

Comment: Other products are working fine, issue with only one product

Comment: I edited and saved the particular product from magento admin then working fine.